# How to make slstatus fit in dwm

Tags: x-dwm

I am trying to setup slstatus in dwm but i cant get it to fit on the screen. I have tried editing the MAXLEN variable in the slstatus config file. I have looked in the dmenu and dwm config files but could not find any relevant variables.

Here is a image showing my problem (ram usage and time is going off screen)
[image]

I am running alpine linux VM in VMware with a 1920x1080 monitor.

Comment: Works fine for me: https://i.imgur.com/woxrmDX.png. What does your configuration look like?

Comment: Yes indeed, once I set something wrong and I had the same problem.